# sqlite on iphone can open db but not prepare statements

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I'm brand new to using sqlite so I may have missed something basic.

I've created a database and copied it into my app's document's directory. I'm able to open it but when I make a call to sqlite3_prepare_v2 I receive SQLITE_ERROR, "SQL error or missing database".

here's my code:

```
sqlite3 *database;
if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) 
{
  sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
  NSString *sqlStatement = @"select * from dbname";
  int result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sqlStatement UTF8String], -1, &compiledStatement, nil);
  ...
}
```

the same sql statement works in the terminal.

I've found this question in a few places either without answers or with solutions that don't fix my problem. I'm hoping someone here will be able to help. Thanks.

Edit:

Got it to work using Firefox's SQLite Manager, was a problem with the database file created through the terminal.

Comment: What does `dbPath` hold?

Comment: dbPath is the path to the sqlite database file located in the app's Documents area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `sqlite3_open`, a new empty database will automatically be created if it does not already exist in the given location in `dbPath`. If you instead use `sqlite3_open_v2` you are able to control it to just open an existing databse instead of creating it if missing. Just pass the flag `SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE` in the third parameter.

If the database have somehow not been copied into the applications documents folder as expected, the latter method should catch this.

Hope this helps,

Claus

Comment: Thanks, I bet that was the case, it was probably opening a new db instead of my sqlite file.